# What is the best way to create persistent memcached connections under mod_perl?

Tags: perl, memcached, mod-perl

I know there is a module like `Apache::DBI` which allows to use persistent connections to database under mod_perl.

Is there an easy way to make something like this? Could you recommend any memcached pooling package?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Apache::DBI's source code, you'll see that it just puts the database handle in a lexical scoped at the top of the package. It's easy enough to do this for Memcached.  Make a new package, with a `my $memcached;` at the top, then have an `init()` method make the connection and save it in that lexical.  Then have a `getConnection()` method to fetch the connection in your code.  That method needs to check if the connection is still alive and reconnect if needed.

Lastly, setup a `PerlChildInitHandler` to call `init()` (see Apache::DBI `connect_on_init()`).