# using cached connections to memcached under mod_perl

Tags: perl, memcached, mod-perl

I have initialized a Cache::Memcached::Fast object in the mod_perl startup for re-use by the scripts

For eg in startup.pl

```
 $GLOBAL::memc = new Cache::Memcached::Fast({servers => '192.168.1.1:11211'});
```

I notice that when multiple calls to $GLOBAL::memc->get()  happen simultaneously to the scripts the data for 1 process is sometimes copied  to the results of the other

How can I make sure the memc handles are multi process-safe

This link explains a different problem , that the memcache handle dies  .. but I guess this is also because of the same reason 
[What is the best way to create persistent memcached connections under mod_perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344162/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-persistent-memcached-connections-under-mod-perl)

Comment: How does calling get() copy anything anywhere?  Also according to the docs: `Currently recognized keys are: servers...The value is a reference to an array of server addresses.`  Your value is a string.

Answer (score 1):

[Is Memcached get and put methods are thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611799/is-memcached-get-and-put-methods-are-thread-safe)

use cas(compare and set) function to have proper syncronization between processes/threads.